# Calculate the degree of the field extension $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)\mid\Bbb{Q}(b)$

Tags: polynomials, extension-field

> Given $a=\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{-5}$ and $b=5^{\frac{1}{4}}$, find de degree of the field extension $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)\mid\Bbb{Q}(b)$

I tried to compute the minimal polynomials of $a$ and $b$, and I got

$$P_{\Bbb{Q},a}(t)=t^4+100$$
and

$$P_{\Bbb{Q},b}(t)=t^4-5$$

But both polynomials had degree four, which are not prime twins, so I can't conclude anything about de degree of $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)\mid\Bbb{Q}(b)$.

I also noticed that we can write $a$ as

$$a=b^2+ib^2$$
but I don't know how that would help to solve this problem. 
I'm looking for tips to point me to the right direction, not just an entire answer to this problem, but anyway, any help would be highly appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your observation that $a = b^2 + ib^2$, we have that

$$\mathbb{Q}(a, b) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}, i)$$

You now want to compute the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}, i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})$.

To this end, it suffices to figure out what the minimum polynomial of $i$ is over the small field.

Comment: So then $deg(t^2+1)=[\Bbb{Q}(a,b): \Bbb{Q}(b)]=2$, right?

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, looks fine. Alternatively, $\mathbb{Q}(a, b)$ is a degree $8$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ is degree $4$. Hence, $8/4 = 2$.

Comment: but how do you find the degree of $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)|\Bbb{Q}$ without finding first the degree of $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)| \Bbb{Q}(b)$?

Comment: One way is to see that the minimum polynomial of $5^{1/4} + i$ has [degree 8](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+polynomial+5%5E(1%2F4)+%2B+i), so the extension has degree at least 8.